# Como passar valores de uma lista no Ionic3

Tags: array, angular, ionic3

Fala galera, to quebrando cabeça com uma coisa "aprentemente" simples, mais nem tanto... tenho um json simples com id e nome, com aproximadamente 25 registros, tenho que pegar somente os registros selecionados pelo usuário para gerar uma nova tela conforme os itens selecionados, estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-list-header>
    Disciplinas
  </ion-list-header>

  <ion-item *ngFor="let dsc of disciplinas">
    <ion-label>{{ dsc.disciplina }}</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle (ngModel)="slcDisc[dsc]" checked="false"></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

No controller quando visualizo o iten slcDisc[] ele da como um undefined, minha dúvida é como pegar esses valores do lado do controller!?

Comment: pode fornecer o código do controller?

Comment: Isso que estou tentando fazer no controller e não estou conseguindo! Quando submeto o form, estou verificando os demais campos com o console.log() e estão vindo certinhos, quando exibo os itens selecionados no toogle dá como undefined!

Answer (score 1):

Fiz de uma forma um pouco diferente. Nao sei se super compliquei, ou seja, se há uma forma mais simples de fazer, mas funciona. O beneficio aqui é não ser necessario passar pelo "submit" para ter as alteracoes no controller.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      Disciplinas
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let dsc of disciplinas">
      <ion-label>{{ dsc.disciplina }}</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle (ngModel)="slcDisc[dsc]" checked="false" (ionChange)="mudou(dsc.disciplina)"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <button (click)="teste()"> Final</button>
```

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'teste-tog',
    templateUrl: 'teste-tog.component.html',
  })
export class TestTogComponent {

    disciplinas: Array<{disciplina: string}> = new Array<{disciplina: string}>();
    slcDisc: Array<{disciplina: string}> = new Array<{disciplina: string}>();

    constructor(){
        this.disciplinas.push({disciplina: 'portugues'}, {disciplina: 'matematica'}, {disciplina: 'geografia'});        
    }

    teste(){
        console.log(this.slcDisc);
    }

    mudou(disciplina: string){
        let indice = this.slcDisc.findIndex( (v) => {
            return v.disciplina == disciplina
        })
console.log(indice + ' ' + disciplina);
        if ( indice == -1 )
            this.slcDisc.push({disciplina: disciplina})
        else
            this.slcDisc.splice(indice, 1);

    }
}
```

Passei só a propriedade disciplina para o metodo mudar mas vc tb pode passar o objeto dsc inteiro. Só seria preciso alterar a assinatura do metodo.